# "Disk not formatted" warning after writing bootloader

Tags: debugging, assembly, bootloader, bootstrapping

I recently wrote a simple bootloader in assembly for floppy disk booting.  I used 'debug' command on my Windows XP virtual machine, to write on the first sector of floppy disk image.  It works, which is good. Now, I am trying to load the second stage bootloader (or kernel) into the memory by reading sectors: I wrote the second stage bootloader to be read as well as modified first stage bootloader.

To make this happen, I need to copy the second stage bootloader into the floppy disk. I clicked the A: icon on the windows explorer, trying to copy it, but the message I got was "The disk in drive A: is not formatted.  Do you want to format it now?"  At this stage, I got some questions in a row.

My questions are:

1. How do I make windows acknowledge the bootloader I wrote, so that I can copy other files in? (Or is it even possible?)
2. If this is not an option, do I always need to use either "debug" or "partcopy" to copy all other files into the disk?
3. Can I copy the second stage and/or other files into any empty sectors?
4. Debug command is gone in Windows 7 and partcopy windows version didn't allow me to write on the first sector of the disk.  What are the alternatives? (Trying to avoid working on VM.)

I am sorry for asking so many question on one thread.  I thought it was easy to ask in one, cause they are all related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Does your boot sector have a partition table at byte 446? It is needed to have, well.. partitions. A valid file system is also needed.
2. If there isn't any valid supported file system, then yes, you will need to use specialized tools to write the data directly to sectors.
3. If you don't employ a file system, the entire disk is free to use as you see fit. If you want to use a file system, it will need some sectors to work. Ideally you should also go through the file system to find sector(s) of your second stage.
4. You could use a specialized tool made specifically for writing boot sectors or disk images, or you could use dd:

   ```
   dd of=/dev/fd0 if=bootsector.img bs=512 count=1
   ```

Comment: No it does not have partition table.  I was following many different tutorials and non of them had it, so I was not aware about it.  Do I need to implement this for the Windows to recognise the disk as formatted?

Comment: Yes. But then you would probably need to keep track of where your second stage ends up when copying it to disk, perhaps by querying the file system.

Comment: So, it sounds like that you are suggesting two things: Implement partition table for windows' acknowledgement + simply copy my second stage into the sector(s) where I want to put on the disk, instead of allowing windows to put it wherever it wants, so I don't have to search.  Did I understand it right ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment by the way.  I would up vote, but I don't have the privilege yet.

Comment: Yes you could do that, but remember that you need sectors to accomodate the file system that you choose. The partition needs a valid file system for the operating system to 'accept' it.

Comment: I think I get it, sort of, but not completely.  I will have to read some more about partition table.  Thanks :)

Comment: If anyone could help me with other questions I had above, it would be great, too :)

Comment: I couldn't appreciate any more.  Basically, you answered it all in the comments, but I just didn't get it, due to my lack of knowledge. Thanks Jens. Study time now :)